# Devicemapper maintenance- dmsetup is missing

Tags: centos, rhel, docker, device-mapper

I manage docker environment on RHEL 7.1 host. Currently I use docker engine v1.9 and what I'd like to do is to upgrade this docker engine to v1.13.
My docker engine uses devicemappers as storage, and I noticed that almost 75% of its disk space is used by orphaned volumes, so I would like to take an opportunity and remove old devicemapper and create new one.

So I am looking for a tool which can allow me to operate on devicemappers.

I found tool [`dmsetup`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/dmsetup.html) but this one is missing on my machine (command not found on rhel 7.1).

When I try to look for this with yum:

```
yum provides dmsetup
```

I am getting:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, package_upload, product-id, subscription-manager
No matches found
```

Do you know how can I get this tool or maybe you can suggest another tool for managing devicemapper?

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand what you're asking - if you add more data about what you're trying to do, maybe we can help better.

But to answer the question as it is - using the following command you can find out which package provides which command:

```
yum provides dmsetup
```

This will show you that the package is called `device-mapper` - then simply do:

```
yum install device-mapper
```

Comment: After entering "yum provide dmsetup" I get an error: "No matches found"

Comment: Do you have any repositories configured? Do `yum repolist` and if you don't, configure some repositories. Check the .repo files in /etc/yum.repos.d/. If there is no other way, try to add the install DVD as a repo.